# Error installing package

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.3

good evening!

I am trying to install a package, but it is displaying the following error:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for r0bdiablo/laravel5-phumbor ^0.1.0 -> satisfiable by r0bdiablo/laravel5-phumbor[0.1.0].
    - r0bdiablo/laravel5-phumbor 0.1.0 requires 99designs/phumbor dev-master -> satisfiable by 99designs/phumbor[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

Image with error

[image]

He informs that the problem is with a dependency. But I have no idea how to solve the problem. can anybody help me?

Comment: can you share your composer.json file

Comment: yes! I edited it in edition.

Answer (score 3):

```
composer require r0bdiablo/laravel5-phumbor "dev-master"
```

Comment: thank you so much! Solved my problem! There were hours that I was trying to solve.